# simple logic - javascript involved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i dont want any plugin for this. i have 3 images which are shown in 2 different ways.

[image]

i want to write onclick function in each `img`, so that when i click the small one, it should replace the big one. my vision is this:

```
<img class="locationfoto" src="image-path">  <--- main foto 
<img class="locationfoto1" src="image-path-1" onclick="moveme(this)">
<img class="locationfoto2" src="image-path-2" onclick="moveme(this)">
```

my js:

```
function moveme(me){
   // how can i do this?
}
```

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can set the image displayed in `locationfoto` as:

```
function moveme(me){
    $('.locationfoto').attr('src', me.src);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function moveme(me)
{
   var imgsrc = me.src ;
   $('.locationfoto').attr('src', imgsrc)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
 table#thumbnails{
  background-color:white;
}
 table#thumbnails tr td img
{
cursor: pointer;
 }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showImage(image){
var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
mainImage.src = image; 
}
function toggleThumbnails(){
var thumbnails = document.getElementById('thumbnails');
if(thumbnails.style.display == 'block'){
thumbnails.style.display = 'none'; 
 } else {
thumbnails.style.display = 'block'; 
}
}
```

```
<input type="button" value="Show/hide thumbnail list" onclick="toggleThumbnails()" />
<table id="thumbnails" style="display:none;">
<tr>
<td><img src="thumb1.png" title="Item 1" onclick="showImage('img1.png')" /></td>
<td><img src="thumb2.png" title="Item 2" onclick="showImage('img2.png')" /></td>
<td><img src="thumb3.png" title="Item 3" onclick="showImage('img3.png')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="thumb4.png" title="Item 4" onclick="showImage('img4.png')" /></td>
<td><img src="thumb5.png" title="Item 5" onclick="showImage('img5.png')" /></td>
<td><img src="thumb6.png" title="Item 6" onclick="showImage('img6.png')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="thumb7.png" title="Item 7" onclick="showImage('img7.png')" /></td>
<td><img src="thumb8.png" title="Item 8" onclick="showImage('img8.png')" /></td>
<td><img src="thumb9.png" title="Item 9" onclick="showImage('img9.png')" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
<img id="mainImage" src="img1.png" /> 
</div>
```

Well, the example you refer to is created in Flash, so to get similar fancy look and feel in javascript is not easy.

But it is quite easy to get similar functionality in javascript, but not with the fancy smooth transitions, and fancy look of the tooltips etc (it is possible, but requires a lot more...). A simple example of displaying image from click on thumbnails could be something like this:

Answer (score 1):

An example without using jQuery. You will need to specify an id for the main photo:

```
<body>
<img class="locationfoto" src="image-path" id="main">  <--- main foto 
<img class="locationfoto1" src="image-path-1" onclick="moveme(this)">
<img class="locationfoto2" src="image-path-2" onclick="moveme(this)">

<script>
function moveme(me) {
  document.getElementById('main').src = me.src;
}

</script>
</body>
```